# append new object (view)

Tags: django, django-views

I'm reassigning a new object to `movie`. I want to append new object to `movie`. What should I do?

```
for language in categories.language.all():
        movie = Movie.objects.filter(is_active=True,language=language.id)
```

thank you
UPDATE: In `categories.language.all()` I've object like this.

```
English
Etc
French
```

I want to filter `Movie` model by theses languages.

MYSQL query > `select * from move where language = 'English' and language = 'French'`

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. Presumably `Movie` is a class you wrote, so you know how to append to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off using [in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
languages = [ language.id for language in categories.language.all() ]
movies = Movie.objects.filter(is_active=True, language__in=languages)
```

And assuming that `categories.language.all()` returns a QuerySet (we can't tell from your question), it's even simpler:

```
languages = categories.language.all()
movies = Movie.objects.filter(is_active=True, language__in=languages)
```

Comment: It worked `movies = Movie.objects.filter(is_active=True, language__in=languages)` Thanks alot :-)